# If-Else nest redundant?

Tags: c++, if-statement

Currently, I am taking a C++ course at my local college, and was given a debugging assignment. In the instructions for this assignment, I was told that the only thing really wrong with this code, is that the conditions for the nested if-else-if statements on lines 82-89 are redundant, however, I cannot see another way to get the same results without having those conditions stay the same...any tips or such would be greatly appreciated!

```
#include <iostream>
#include <conio.h>
#include <iomanip>

using namespace std;

const int   BASE_COST = 10;
const int   LOW_LIMIT = 20;
const int   MID_LIMIT = 40;
const int   HIGH_LIMIT = 60;
const double    LOW_CHECKS = .10;
const double    MIDLOW_CHECKS = .08;
const double    MIDHIGH_CHECKS = .06;
const double    HIGH_CHECKS = .04;

int main()
{
int numOfChecks;
double multiplierValue;
double totalFee;

cout << fixed << showpoint;
cout << setprecision(2);
cout << "Please enter the number of checks you used this month: ";
cin >> numOfChecks;

if(numOfChecks < 0)
{
    cout << "Number of checks can't be negative. Program ends.\n";
    exit(1);    //terminate the program with error code 1
}

//the following line runs only if the program did not terminate, so start over if-else
if(numOfChecks < LOW_LIMIT)
    multiplierValue = LOW_CHECKS;
else if(numOfChecks < MID_LIMIT)
    multiplierValue = MIDLOW_CHECKS;
else if(numOfChecks >= MID_LIMIT && numOfChecks < HIGH_LIMIT)
    multiplierValue = MIDHIGH_CHECKS;
else if (numOfChecks >= HIGH_LIMIT)
    multiplierValue = HIGH_CHECKS;  

totalFee = BASE_COST + numOfChecks * multiplierValue;

cout << "Your total for this month is $" << totalFee;

_getch();
return 0;
}
```

Comment: `nested if-else-if statements on lines 82-89 are redundant` a) We dont have line numbers, b) that snippet is 49 lines long c) i dont see any nested if/else

Comment: Consider the last condition in the `if`/`else` ladder. Based on the earlier conditions, what can you conclude about the value of `numOfChecks` for execution to reach that point?

Comment: The original code had instructions and such above the actual code, I took that out when posting it here, which is probably why the lines are less than that, though as for the nested if/else, that's what my instructor referred to that series of if/else-if statements right near the end of the code.

Comment: @Borgleader True, but there's only one group of if-else tests that this question could really apply to. Not that hard to find.

Comment: @DanMašek Considering b, it was possible that there was a nested if in code that was accidentally left out of the question. At which point a & c are relevant points.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This part `else if(numOfChecks >= MID_LIMIT && numOfChecks < HIGH_LIMIT)` looks redundant. Provided you keep the order of the range checks, it can be simplified to just `else if (numOfChecks < HIGH_LIMIT)`, same as the one following it (which is just not needed) so that the whole piece looks like:

```
//the following line runs only if the program did not terminate, so start over if-else
if (numOfChecks < LOW_LIMIT)
    multiplierValue = LOW_CHECKS;
else if (numOfChecks < MID_LIMIT)
    multiplierValue = MIDLOW_CHECKS;
else if (numOfChecks < HIGH_LIMIT)
    multiplierValue = MIDHIGH_CHECKS;
else
    multiplierValue = HIGH_CHECKS;
```

Comment: That makes so much sense, and I can't see any other way to make it less redundant, thank you so much!!

Answer (score 0):

Indeed, all the conditions are redundant: use an algorithm :)

**<kbd>[Live On Coliru](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/e2372983bce861f2)</kbd>**

```
#include <iomanip>
#include <map>
#include <iostream>

namespace {
    using Threshold = unsigned;
    using Rate      = double;

    static Rate constexpr BASE_COST = 10.0;

    std::map<Threshold, Rate, std::greater<> > const tariffs {
        { 0, .10},
        {20, .08},
        {40, .06},
        {60, .04},
    };

    double fee(unsigned numOfChecks) {
        auto rate = tariffs.lower_bound(numOfChecks);
        return BASE_COST + rate->second * numOfChecks;
    }
}

int main() {
    unsigned numOfChecks;
    std::cout << "Please enter the number of checks you used this month: ";

    if (std::cin >> numOfChecks) {
        std::cout 
            << "\nYour total for this month is $"
            << std::fixed << std::showpoint << std::setprecision(2) << fee(numOfChecks)
            << std::endl;
    } else {
        std::cout << "Invalid input\n";
        return 1;
    }
}
```

Prints e.g.

```
Please enter the number of checks you used this month: 10
Your total for this month is $11.00

Please enter the number of checks you used this month: 20
Your total for this month is $11.60

Please enter the number of checks you used this month: 30
Your total for this month is $12.40

Please enter the number of checks you used this month: 40
Your total for this month is $12.40

Please enter the number of checks you used this month: 50
Your total for this month is $13.00

Please enter the number of checks you used this month: 60
Your total for this month is $12.40

Please enter the number of checks you used this month: 70
Your total for this month is $12.80

Please enter the number of checks you used this month: 80
Your total for this month is $13.20

Please enter the number of checks you used this month: 90
Your total for this month is $13.60

Please enter the number of checks you used this month: 100
Your total for this month is $14.00
```